# HTTP code 400 as converting Javascript POST to Python POST

Tags: javascript, python

I'm converting piece of Javascript code to Python code. The code is sending POST to text extracting server. In JS code, POST is sent successfully, and the response is correct. But in Python, I've got HTTP code 400.

In **request.post(url=url, headers=headers, data={data.encode('UTF-8')})**,
I've tried "data" parameter as *normal string* and *dictionary* type.

Javascript code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://35.240.240.251/api/v1/real-estate-extraction";
    request.open("POST", url, false);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    var responseText = document.getElementById('response');

    request.onload = (res) => {
        data = res['target']['response'];
        data = JSON.parse(data);

        for (var i = 0 ; i < data[0].tags.length ; i++){
            if (data[0].tags[i].type == "addr_street"){
                features.push(data[0].tags[i].content);
                document.write("street: " + data[0].tags[i].content + "\n");
            }
        }
};

    // var input = prompt("Input:");
    request.send(JSON.stringify([inputUser]));
```

Python code:

```py
import requests
import json

url = "http://35.240.240.251/api/v1/real-estate-extraction"

data = 'Chính chủ 02 lô đất Củ Chi , liền kề nhau.  Dt: 1.000m2 giá 770 triệu/ 1.000m2 , ' \
       'sổ còn thơm mùi giấy chưa qua kinh doanh , ' \
       'không dính quy hoạch gi cả . Liên Hệ : 0948881115 để đặt cọc nhanh lẹ.'

request = requests.Session()
request.verify = False

headers = {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
}

response = request.post(url=url, headers=headers, data={data.encode('UTF-8')})

print(response.status_code) #result: 400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Code:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://35.240.240.251/api/v1/real-estate-extraction"

data_text = 'Chính chủ 02 lô đất Củ Chi , liền kề nhau.  Dt: 1.000m2 giá 770 triệu/ 1.000m2 , ' \
       'sổ còn thơm mùi giấy chưa qua kinh doanh , ' \
       'không dính quy hoạch gi cả . Liên Hệ : 0948881115 để đặt cọc nhanh lẹ.'

data_list = [ data_text ]

request = requests.Session()

## request.verify = False

##headers = {
##       'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
##}

headers = { }

response = request.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data_list)

print('RESPONSE_CODE: %s' % response.status_code) 

print('RESPONSE_DATA:\n %s' % json.dumps(response.json(), ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

... You can use `json=` in the `post` and it requests will handle the content-type header for you automatically

... the output from running the code is:

```
RESPONSE_CODE: 200
RESPONSE_DATA:
 [
    {
        "score": 694.771240234375,
        "tags": [
            {
                "content": "chính chủ 02 lô",
                "type": "normal"
            },
            {
                "content": "đất",
                "type": "realestate_type"
            },
            {
                "content": "củ chi",
                "type": "addr_district"
            },
            {
                "content": ", liền kề nhau . dt :",
                "type": "normal"
            },
            {
                "content": "1 . 000 m 2",
                "type": "area"
            },
            {
                "content": "giá",
                "type": "normal"
            },
            {
                "content": "770 triệu / 1 . 000 m 2",
                "type": "price"
            },
            {
                "content": ", sổ còn thơm mùi giấy chưa qua",
                "type": "normal"
            },
            {
                "content": "kinh doanh",
                "type": "potential"
            },
            {
                "content": ", không dính quy hoạch gi cả . liên hệ : 0948881115 để đặt cọc nhanh lẹ .",
                "type": "normal"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

(It would be better to check the documentation for the API to confirm how it is really supposed to be used)